# How to show image using javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, css

My javascript code is as bellow where "samson decosta" is the image name that is stored in mysql database. I am fetching  this image and want to show in a div background_image.

```
document.getElementById("image_chk").style.backgroundImage="url(img/"+ clicked_id+".jpg)";
```

My problem is that when ever I store image name with space in between the words, it can't showing the image. However when I replace space to underscore (or no space between words ) it showing me the image.

where,

clicked_id =samson decosta (cant able to fetch this image because space in between words).

clicked_id =samson_decosta (able to fetch this image).

clicked_id =samsondecosta (able to fetch this image).

Comment: please avoid spaces between words in the image name because the space may be replaced by some special characters which cause problems

Comment: Is JavaScript automatically take space as a special character ?
My requiremen is space in between two words.

Comment: you can do one thing, while inserting replace space by underscore and again while you are retrieving you can replace underscore by space to get the original one

Comment: Right now I am doing this only.
But I wanted to achive with space .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quotes around parameter value in `url`

```
document
  .getElementById("image_chk")
  .style.backgroundImage="url( 'img/"+ clicked_id+".jpg' )";
```